# How to calculate this specific integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm doing an exercise on Durret's Probability: Theory and Examples and I encountered a calculation of the following integral:
$$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\int_{-x}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi s}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2s}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi (t - s)}} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2(t - s)}}\mathrm{d} y,$$
where $t > s > 0$.

I know the answer is $\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2 \pi} \arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{s}{t}}}$. But I don't know how to get there. I would appreciate any hint. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We start performing the cahnge $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2s}}\rightarrow u$ and  $\frac{y}{\sqrt{2(t-s)}}\rightarrow v$

$$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}x\int_{-x}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi s}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2s}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi (t - s)}} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2(t - s)}}\mathrm{d} y=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}u\int_{-u\sqrt{\frac{s}{t-s}}}^\infty  e^{-u^2} e^{-v^2}\mathrm{d} v,$$

[image]

(in the picture $a=\sqrt{\frac{s}{t-s}}$). Now, using polar coordinates we have

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\theta_0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^\infty  e^{-r^2} r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d} y=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\theta_0}{2\pi}$$

Here, $\theta_0=\arctan\left(-\sqrt{\frac{s}{t-s}}\right)$ and using trigonometric rules you can arrive to $\theta_0=-\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{s}{t}}}$, obtaining the desired result

Comment: Thank you very much. Using polar coordinate conversion is clever.